# KoaJS: Ending a response

Tags: node.js, koa

I have a simple `koa` echo server:

```
var koa = require('koa');
var app = koa();

app.use(require('koa-trie-router')(app));

app.route('/echo/:word')
.post(function* (next) {
  this.response.body = { echo: this.params.word };
  yield next;
});

app.listen(3000);
```

When I curl that end point I see this:

```
* Connection #0 to host localhost left intact
{"echo":"hello"}%
```

But I can't figure out how to close that connection via the `koa` api. How do I complete a response?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

koa uses a middleware pattern. `yield next` is used to go to the next middleware for your request handler. Since you don't have anymore middleware, you shouldn't `yield next` in this case. Just set the body and let the function close.

Answer (score 0):

Just use:

```
app.route('/echo/:word')
.post(function* (next) {
     ctx.throw(401, { echo: this.params.word })
});
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved by adding more information on what the code does and how it helps the OP.